# Jhipster authentication header

Tags: authentication, spring-security, jhipster

We are starting project based on the great jhipster work.
While we would like to keep the option to be session based (with a login page), we also have the need for enalble clients pass user info in the header of each request,
(e.g. Authenticate: username:password) to have it session less like without login, as regular users do.

Do we have this implemented OOTB? If not, what is the best approach for having that?

Thanks ahead for any comment & answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JHipster supports both "session-based" (with a login page, and the Spring Security token is stored in the HTTP Session), and OAuth2 (which is stateless, and the token are stored in the database).
The OAuth2 mechanism also uses a login page, but I guess you could make it work without it if needed -> isn't this the best solution for you?
We also have another stateless mecanism in the pipe, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/892

Comment: Thanks for answering Julien, OAuth2 might be the way to go, I'll give it a try. 

Can I change the session base approach an enable authentication in each request?

Comment: Epsilon, the client (which uses AngularJS) stores the authentication token in local browser storage. This token is then injected into the http header on each request. The server checks for the auth header and authenticates each request.

Comment: @Rori, is this the case in both authentication options, session based, and session less?